# FILL table "users" update column "Additional_field_1" with column "ID" with 7 random numbers without first two numbers is column "ID"

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

I have table `USERS` with columns `ID` and `ADDITIONAL_FIELD_1` (empty).

In column `ID` I have 1000 queries with random 7 numbers in field.

I need to fill `ADDITIONAL_FIELD_1` with the same numbers as are in column `ID` but without first 2 numbers.

That doesn't work:

```
UPDATE USERS SET
    ADDITIONAL_FIELD_1 = ID
WHERE ID > 2
```

Comment: "_That doesn't work_" - Why not? What does it do that's different to what you require? Adding some example result data would be useful to help people understand your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the ADDITIONAL_FIELD_1 value to the last 5 digits of the 7 digit ID value you could do this:

```
UPDATE USERS SET ADDITIONAL_FIELD_1 = RIGHT(CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(7)), 5)
```

Comment: What is the difference if I run this:
update users set ADDITIONAL_FIELD_1=right(id, 5)

Comment: The cast is just for extra safety, it will work without it too.